# Qgis2threejs plugin and 3d maps

Tags: qgis2threejs

I'm using qGIS 2.18.13 and I downloaded the plugin qGis2threejs to make 3D maps. I'm wondering how it works because it only works with some DEM rasters and not with everything. In particular, when showing the 3D map, it makes outputs like the one i posted.
I would also like to make 3D maps from Raster values not only with DEMs, but from other ones. Any suggestions?

[image: error]

Comment: that could be a unit problem (when a DEM has coordinate in degree and elevation in meter)

Comment: mmh, ok.. And do you know how to change the parameters of a raster in order to consider its points as meters (and change coordinates in degrees)?

Comment: For hillshading you use a Z factor maybe Qgis2threejs has an equivalent, the other way is to re-project your raster in a coordinate system with the same unit as the elevation

Comment: Thanks, you were right! By changing both the z factor or the scale it worked perfectly!